# Windows phone set different user agent for every request

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, mobile, windows-phone-8.1

I am working on one of my windows 8.1 mobile app. I have included one web browser control in this app and it's linked up with my asp.net web site. So basically it's an app which using web site in background.

The problem is that in my web site i have added some checks based on user agent header. However while request coming from this app it's have different user agent for first request and another ajax request which is being sent by web site after loading the page. Below are two different user agents which are coming from windows app.

1. Mozilla/5.0 (Mobile; Windows Phone 8.1; Android 4.0; ARM; Trident/7.0; Touch; rv:11.0; IEMobile/11.0; Microsoft; Lumia 535 Dual SIM) like iPhone OS 7_0_3 Mac OS X AppleWebKit/537 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile Safari/537
2. Mozilla/5.0 (Windows Phone 8.1; ARM; Trident/7.0; Touch; rv:11.0; WebBrowser/8.1; IEMobile/11.0; Microsoft; Lumia 535 Dual SIM) like Gecko